# django-rest-framework-docs methods description

Tags: django-rest-framework

Good Day.

I wanted to make documentation for my api. I use this library

https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-docs

Me need to add description of methods, but this means doesn't work https://yadi.sk/i/y3hodAvn3TMRJ3

My code

```
def get(self, request):
    """
    description for method
    """
```

I also tried so

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    me:
        Return current user.
    update:
        update users
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you share more code ?

Comment: if I understood correctly in this library is not supported description of methods https://www.drfdocs.com/settings/

Answer (score 0):

You using the wrong library. From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/), the library you are using and related DRF libraries are for -

1. Documentation of API endpoints.
2. Automatically generated code samples
   for each of the available API client libraries.
3. Support for API interaction.

They are not for documenting your docstrings. For that, use a python documentation library, like [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

Relevant link - http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/documentation/